# How to Remove the Decimal Point in string using regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq

I want to format a string as a removing decimal and keep only integers , but the decimal contains some following zeros after the decimal. How do I format it such that those 0's disappear?

I have Input string data :

```
var xRaw= ",String30.0,String1.0,String0.0,String-1.0,StringOFF".Split(',').ToList();
```

How to get out put format :   `"30,1,0,-1,OFF"`

```
var ValuesString = xRaw.Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, "[^OF0-9-,\\.]", "")).ToList()
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
```

Above regex will remove the string and keep required string "OFF" but its keeps another which is next to "." point.

Comment: Is there some requirement to use regex?  You could chain together some `string.Replace` calls for the same effect.

Comment: mate  its not possible because we dont know  the "string" data which will be next numeric value

Comment: If the `String` is composed of unknown chars, it is quite hard to help without knowing the exact specifications. How do you know where this `OFF` should be kept and why?

Comment: Assuming this is for some specific purpose and it will always have "String" and keep this format... would replace with "\.\d+|String" be sufficient (and then just remove first comma from string)?

Comment: Well, it is too unclear. But try updating your pattern with `@"[^OF0-9-,.]|\.[0-9]+"`. A better option: `Regex.Replace(x, @"(OFF)|[^0-9-,.]|\.[0-9]+", "$1")`

Comment: this regex pattern worked for me  :) @"[^OF0-9-,.]|\.\d+"      wiktor thanks

Comment: @RanjithMurthy: Glad to help. Please consider accepting/upvoting my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may fix your pattern (if it works enough well for you) by simply adding `\.[0-9]+` alternative to also remove fractional parts of float numbers.

```
@"[^OF0-9-,.]|\.[0-9]+".
```

A better option is to keep `OFF` as a *sequence* of chars, not just any `O` or `F`:

```
Regex.Replace(x, @"(OFF)|[^0-9-,.]|\.[0-9]+", "$1")
```

Here, `OFF` is captured into Group 1 and `$1` backreference restores it in the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

Umm... I think this fits your input string.  Without knowing what variations can happen, there's no way to know if it works on all the data you might get.

```
var xRaw= ",String30.0,String1.0,String0.0,String1.0,StringOFF";
string result = String.Join(",", 
                   Regex.Matches(xRaw, "\\d+.?\\d*|OFF")
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(m => {
                                        decimal d;
                                        if(decimal.TryParse(m.Value, out d))
                                            return ((int)d).ToString();
                                        return m.Value;
                                     }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
var input = ",String30.0,String1.0,String0.0,String-1.0,StringOFF";
var output = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(input, @"[^OF\-\d.,]", ""), @"\.\d", "").TrimStart(',');
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8IordG

Answer (score 0):

```
string giventxt = "text text 54654654200500.0000 text text";
string[] arry = giventxt.Split('.');
string arry1 = arry[1];
string[] arry2 = arry1.Split(' ');
string completestr = arry[0] + " " + arry2[1] + " " + arry2[2];
```

Comment: Please provide a comment together with your answer, code-only answers are considered low-quality.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Step1: Split the given text with "." char,Step2: Assign arry[1](0000 text text) to the string variable arry1,Step3: Split arry[1] with " " char,Step4: Concat arry[0] + " " + arry2[1] + " " + arry2[2] to form the required text.

Comment: Guys thank u for ur suggestions.Now check i have included the explanation